# CursorWindowAllocationException in standard ORMLite method

Tags: android, sql, ormlite, android-cursor

I need save some objects in DB. I'm using this code in my Dao class.

```
  public void saveActions(List<Action> actionList) throws SQLException {
    for (Action action : actionList) {
        createOrUpdate(action);
      }
  }
```

And sometimes I have CursorWindowAllocationException in `createOrUpdate()` function.

Does anyone have solution of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up the source of `CursorWindowAllocationException` it reads:

> This exception is thrown when a CursorWindow couldn't be allocated,
>   most probably due to memory not being available.

If you follow the stack, you'll see that the call `com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidDatabaseConnection.queryForLong` is creating a cursor for every `createOrUpdate` call.

So what's likely happening here is that there are too many `Cursors` being created before the memory is freed.

You should execute these calls in a [transaction](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#Transactions), or better yet, use [batch tasks](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html#callBatchTasks). E.g.

```
actionDao.callBatchTasks(new Callable<Void>() {
        public Void call() throws SQLException {
            for (Action action : actionList) {
                actionDao.createOrUpdate(action);
            }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You must call `cursor.close();` in **finally { }** block when you do not need cursor anymore. Cursor allocation will fail without calling *close()* on cursor after some time when system resources for cursor allocation will be not available.

Comment: But I don't use cursor manually. I just use `createOrUpdate();` and all other logic runs inside orm library. Well how I can see no one knows why ormlite fails.

Comment: Are not you loading some big data e.g. images from DB? Could you provide more code? What do you mean by "sometimes" you get CursorWindowAllocationException please?