# Several different crashes with Android Room database - NO IDEA WHY

Tags: android, android-room, android-cursor, android-livedata

We've been having some trouble with Android's Room database lately.

The crashes happen only to certain users, but I cannot reproduce it on my testing device(s) or emulators.
(This also happens SOMETIMES on Firebase test devices)

There are a few exceptions which all seem to be related.

All these exceptions are happening in different lines of our Dao, which is generated by Room.

(Be it a query, insert, update or delete).

```
CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed.

IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: ‘/whatever/database’

SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 266)

SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 778)

SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26)

SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db ‘/whatever/database' to 'fr_FR'.
```

What I've tried:

- StrictMode with 'detectLeakedClosableObjects()'
- Increasing the Cursor's WindowSize
- Moving almost all database calls to a sequential executor (all except LiveData's query implementation)

None of these methods helped, and the bug is still there.

The **LiveData's query is the only one** which is NOT offloaded the default database Executor, as I couldn't find a way to do that.
I suspect this might be the issue, but I'm not entirely sure.

This is the LiveData query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM alarms WHERE deleted =0 ORDER BY isActive DESC, hourOfDay, minuteOfHour")
LiveData<List<Alarm>> getLiveAlarmList();
```

exception examples:

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. 
       at android.database.CursorWindow.(CursorWindow.java:108)
       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:300)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:138)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:219)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:268)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker$1.checkUpdatedTable(SourceFile:358)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.InvalidationTracker$1.run(SourceFile:329)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

This one appears to originate form Room's LiveData InvalidationTracker class.

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=1 (# cursors opened by this proc=1)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.(CursorWindow.java:108)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:225)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:149)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
        at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.database.room.AlarmDao_Impl.getAllAlarms(SourceFile:458)
        at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.database.AlarmHelper.getAllAlarms(SourceFile:29)
        at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.registration.DefaultAlarmRegistrationImpl.onCancelPendingAlarms(SourceFile:36)
        at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.registration.BaseAlarmRegistrationImpl$start$runnable$1.run(SourceFile:26)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

While this one comes from a service that querys for "all alarms". Notice that 'AlarmDao_Impl.getAllAlarms' is generated by Room, and does indeed close the cursor when it's done.

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 266)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:1015)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:147)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:136)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(SourceFile:127)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(SourceFile:115)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(SourceFile:151)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:266)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(SourceFile:96)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SourceFile:54)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(SourceFile:233)
       at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.database.room.AlarmDao_Impl$4.compute(SourceFile:555)
       at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.database.room.AlarmDao_Impl$4.compute(SourceFile:541)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(SourceFile:100)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Another LiveData query crash.

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 778)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:561)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:437)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:401)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:528)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SourceFile:90)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.endTransaction(SourceFile:261)
       at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.database.room.AlarmDao_Impl.update(SourceFile:188)
       at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.registration.DefaultAlarmRegistrationImpl.onCalculateAlarms(SourceFile:58)
       at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.registration.BaseAlarmRegistrationImpl$start$runnable$1.run(SourceFile:37)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

This comes from updating the the object instance (also handled by Room)

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:845)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:836)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:143)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:132)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:219)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:258)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.hasRoomMasterTable(SourceFile:155)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.checkIdentity(SourceFile:123)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(SourceFile:115)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen(SourceFile:151)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:266)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(SourceFile:96)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SourceFile:54)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(SourceFile:233)
       at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.database.room.AlarmDao_Impl$4.compute(SourceFile:321)
       at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.database.room.AlarmDao_Impl$4.compute(SourceFile:307)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(SourceFile:100)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Again, seems to be coming from LiveData's AlarmDao_Impl$4.compute() method

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db '/data/user_de/0/com.sofaking.moonworshipper/databases/alarm-database' to 'fr_FR'.
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setLocaleFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:402)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:223)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.tryAcquireNonPrimaryConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:899)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:609)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:348)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:586)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1353)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1328)
       at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query(SourceFile:161)
       at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(SourceFile:233)
       at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.database.room.AlarmDao_Impl.getAllAlarms(SourceFile:438)
       at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.database.AlarmHelper.getAllAlarms(SourceFile:29)
       at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.registration.DefaultAlarmRegistrationImpl.onCancelPendingAlarms(SourceFile:36)
       at com.sofaking.moonworshipper.registration.BaseAlarmRegistrationImpl$start$runnable$1.run(SourceFile:26)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Same area as the second CursorWindowAllocationException, but with a different crash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, the errors had nothing to do with the database itself.
I had some image assets that were not resized to MDPI, HDPI, or XHDPI. They were only supplied in XXHDPI.

To quote this answer from another thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25861292/8198740

If you look up the source of `CursorWindowAllocationException` it reads:

> This exception is thrown when a CursorWindow couldn't be allocated,
>   most probably due to memory not being available.

So apparently, because the images were taking up so much of the app's heap memory, the cursor couldn't allocate itself.

Now I have none of those crashes.

Comment: Yes, you are right, we had similar issues, especially on low-end devices with 512Mb of memory. So, if you have such an issue or similar you should analyze a memory consumption.